# Merge every 3 elements in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to programming, and would appreciate any help.

Suppose I have the following array. (Note that this array comprises of 6 elements)

```
var data = 
[
  'he' ,
  'l' ,
  'lo',
  'th',
  'e',
  're',

]
```

My goal here, is  to either to create a new array  that joins every three elements, into a single element.

Currently, my novice approach to this problem, is to use a simple for loop, to take each element, and add the index of the element +1 and the index of the element + 2 to the initial element.

The code seems to work partially, but since it iterates through each element and not every 3, it joins the elements too many times.

Here is my code:

```
var data = 
[
  'he' ,
  'l' ,
  'lo',
  'th',
  'e',
  're',

]

var newdata = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 var three = data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+2]
 newdata.push(three)

}
console.log(newdata) // => This will output  'hello', 'lloth' 'lothe' 'there' 'ereundefined' 'reundefinedundefined'
```

The desired output is this:

```
var data = 
[
'hello',
'there',
]
```

To get this existing code working, I assume I would have to delete the element + element +1 and element + 2, so that it doesn't join things unnecessarily  the correctly, but I've had no success with that.

I'm open to other solutions/alternates that get the same output.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Change your `for` loop increment to `3` i.e. `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=3) {`

Comment: Note you have a typo in the question, `var three = data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+1]` should be `var three = data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+2]`

Comment: when you use i++ i will be incremented by one each loop. If you use i+=3 i will be incremented by 3 each loop. Another error is, that you used data[i+1] twice, the second one should be i+2.

Comment: @Starbax I added `i+2` initally, weird. Thanks for the tip, it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const data = 
[
  'he' ,
  'l' ,
  'lo',
  'th',
  'e',
  're',
]
const newdata = []
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=3) { // i+=3 can solve your problem
  const three = data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+2]
  newdata.push(three)
}
console.log(newdata)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Also note that slicing makes a lot more sense, since we can vary the "how many elements" number without needing to change any code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```js
const data =
    [
        'he',
        'l',
        'lo',
        'th',
        'e',
        're',

    ]

const newdata = []
while (data.length){
    newdata.push(data.splice(0,3).join(''))
}
console.log(newdata)
```

Comment: In terms of speed, would the splice method be any faster than the traditional `for` loop method?

Comment: If performance is your concern, you should fix the thing that generates the array you're trying to fix, not the code that fixes it =)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the reduce method for your task:

```js
const output = ["he", "l", "lo", "th", "e", "re"].reduce((acc, next, index) => {
  if (index % 3 === 0) { // if index is 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
    acc.push(next);
  } else { // if not, append to the last element
    acc[acc.length - 1] = acc[acc.length - 1] + next;
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

returns

```
(2) ["hello", "there"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The .slice() method is really helpful here, as it leaves the original array intact and creates a new array based on the indexes provided to it. Then we just iterate over every 3 arrays by incrementing 'i' by 3 every time and add each slice to the array to put it all together.

```
const joinEveryThree = () => {
  let data = ["he", "l", "lo", "th", "e", "re"];
  let newData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
    let chunk = data.slice(i, i+3);
    newData.push(chunk.join(''))
  }
  return newData.join(' ')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You were already very close to the solution. If you don't want to edit the original array, all you need to do is increment the index by 3 instead of 1, and modify the conditional so that if the length of the array isn't a product of 3 you don't get an error:

```
for (var i = 0; i + 2 < data.length; i += 3) {
  newData.push(data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2]);
}
```

If there are one or two extra items at the end of your array, this will ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = ["he", "l", "lo", "th", "e", "re"];
const size = 3;
const newData=new Array(Math.ceil(data .length / size ))
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => data .slice(i * size , i * size  + size ))
    .map(data => data.join('')).join(' ')
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

While we can do this with `for` or `while` loops, a solution not mentioned in other answers is to use a reducer, which allows us to perform this trick as an new assignment, similar to how you use `map`:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const chunkSize = 3;
const chunked = data.reduce((result,_,i) => {
                  const s = data.slice(chunkSize * i,chunkSize * (i+1));
                  if (s.length) result.push(s);
                  return result;
                }, []);

console.log(chunked);
```

In this reducer, we don't actually care about "the elements themselves", we just care about what index we're on, so we can generate slice(0,3) for the first element, slice(4,6) for the second element, etc. and at some point our slices will be empty so we just ignore those.

And because we're using slice, if we have an unbalanced number of elements, we don't end up creating arrays with length 3 don't actually contain 3 elements because they're padded with `undefined` entries.

And of course, we can even make the reducer itself something we generate for a specific chunkSize, so we can stick that in some `utils.js` and just import it where needed.

```js
function sliceReducer(data, chunkSize) {
  return function(result,_,i) {
    const s = data.slice(chunkSize * i,chunkSize * (i+1));
    if (s.length) result.push(s);
    return result;
  };
}

const input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
const chunked = input.reduce(sliceReducer(input, 5), []);

console.log(chunked);
```